# How to use the dynamically generated column in the same query without using join or cte

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm learning SQL. I've a situation where I've to use the same column which I created in runtime. The table is *patient* with 2 columns only which are *dateOfCheckup* and *duration* in minutes.

```
+---------------+-----------------+
| dateOfCheckup |   duration      | 
+---------------+-----------------+
|   2020-05-28  |  30 min         | 
|   2020-05-29  |  30 min         |
|   2020-05-30  |  1 hour         | 
|   2020-06-03  |  1 hour 30 min  | 
|   2020-06-05  |  30 min         |
|   2020-07-21  |  1 hour         |
|   2020-07-22  |  1 hour 30 min  | 
|   2020-07-28  |  1 hour 30 min  | 
+---------------+-----------------+
```

Now I'll create 1 more column in run time i.e. *minutes* (which is just *duration* converted to total minutes as integer value) with this query:

```
select dateOfCheckup, duration,
((case when duration like '% hour%' then substring_index(duration, ' hour', 1) * 60 else 0 end) + (case when duration like '%min%' then substring_index(substring_index(duration, ' min', 1), ' ', -1) + 0 else 0 end)) as minutes from patient;
```

This query is working perfectly. See the result:

```
+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| dateOfCheckup |  duration       |   minutes       |
+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|   2020-05-28  |  30 min         |   30            | 
|   2020-05-29  |  30 min         |   30            |
|   2020-05-30  |  1 hour         |   60            |
|   2020-06-03  |  1 hour 30 min  |   90            |
|   2020-06-05  |  30 min         |   30            |
|   2020-07-21  |  1 hour         |   60            |
|   2020-07-22  |  1 hour 30 min  |   90            |
|   2020-07-28  |  1 hour 30 min  |   90            |
+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

My question is, What if I want to use this newly created column *minutes* in the same query for other tasks such as group by, order by, sum, avg, etc. I'm just asking if there's a scenario like this, then how do we achieve this. I tried using `sum(minutes)`. The error is:

> Unknown column 'minutes' in 'field list'

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a41c5e0b696812a63293d411b6ad44f7). Please help me.

Comment: what do you want the output to be?

Comment: For instance let it be the minutes+10 in one more column.

Comment: provided the slution below, if that works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to treat current query as a sub query and then sum the result

```
SELECT SUM(minutes) AS total_time 
FROM (
    select dateOfCheckup, duration, 
    ((case when duration like '% hour%' then substring_index(duration, ' hour', 1) * 60 else 0 end) + 
    (case when duration like '%min%' then substring_index(substring_index(duration, ' min', 1), ' ', -1) + 0 else 0 end)
    ) as minutes 
from patient
) AS a;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a column alias in another expression in the same query.

Define the aliases in a subquery so you can reference them in the outer query:

```
SELECT t.dateOfCheckup, SUM(t.minutes)
FROM (
    select dateOfCheckup, duration,
      (
       (case when duration like '% hour%' 
             then substring_index(duration, ' hour', 1) * 60 
             else 0 end) 
     + (case when duration like '%min%' 
             then substring_index(substring_index(duration, ' min', 1), ' ', -1) + 0 
             else 0 end)
      ) as minutes 
    from patient
) AS t
GROUP BY t.dateOfCheckup
```

Comment: This is what I wanted to hear "You can't use a column alias in another expression in the same query."

Comment: Can you please look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64025684/how-to-use-group-by-in-a-query-while-using-variables

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exact operation you want to do but using one level sub query you can use this new derived column in whichever way you want,e.g.

```
select dateOfCheckup,duration,max(minutes) over() maxminutes
  from (select dateOfCheckup, duration, ((case when duration like '% hour%' then substring_index(duration, ' hour', 1) * 60 else 0 end) + (case when duration like '%min%' then substring_index(substring_index(duration, ' min', 1), ' ', -1) + 0 else 0 end)) as minutes 
          from patient
       ) p;
```