# How to use GROUP BY in a query while using variables

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I'm using MySql V5.7. I have a table *PatientAppointment*. I need to `GROUP BY` *CDRId* which is a column in the same table. Here's the query:

```
SELECT AppointmentDateTime,
       duration,
       minutes,
       @prev_month := BillingMonth BillingMonth,
       @prev_total := total total
FROM (select AppointmentDateTime,
             duration,
             @cur_dur := ((case when duration like '% hour%' then substring_index(duration, ' hour', 1) * 60 else 0 end) +
                         (case when duration like '%min%' then substring_index(substring_index(duration, ' min', 1), ' ', -1) + 0 else 0 end)) as minutes,

             CASE WHEN @year_month = date_format(AppointmentDateTime, '%Y-%m')
                  THEN @cum_sum := @cum_sum + @cur_dur
                  ELSE @cum_sum := @cur_dur
                  END total,
             @year_month := date_format(AppointmentDateTime, '%Y-%m') BillingMonth

      from PatientAppointment, (SELECT @year_month:='', @cum_sum:=0, @cur_dur:=0) variables
      GROUP BY CDRId  <------ ERROR
      ORDER BY AppointmentDateTime) subquery, 
(SELECT @prev_month:=0, @prev_total:=0) variable
ORDER BY AppointmentDateTime, total
```

Here is a working [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=861e63261cf234bc1b043f8a07a8797f)
Please help me. I want the entire result set to be grouped by *CDRId*

If we cannot use GROUP BY clause here, can we do it some logic changes here.

This is the type of grouping I want. See this:

[image]

I'm getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server v...

Comment: (SELECT '@'prev_month:=0, '@'prev_total:=0) variable, you should not have a comma at the end of this line.Voting to close as typo.

Comment: @P.Salmon, I removed the comma and tried but still not working.

Comment: I editted the question, removed the comma

Comment: Not working means?

Comment: DBFiddle does NOT refer to the description of issue.

Comment: @P.Salmon, Not working means I'm still getting the error on adding GROUP BY clause anywhere.

Comment: GROUP BY does not allow to use UDV - the processing order become unpredictable. Use UDV in subquery then aggregate in outer query without UDV usage.

Comment: @MaciejLos, yes its not the exact thing it is pretty uch the same. If you can add it on fidlle. I can add it here also in my local.

Comment: @Akina, can you please edit my fiddle. Not very sure what you're asking me to do. :-(

Comment: The fiddle does NOT contain `CDRId` column. Edit it.

Comment: I'll quickly add it. 1 min

Comment: And synchronize columns names between fiddle and posted query.

Comment: @Akina, Done. Here the updated fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=206e9f9d6d2377b8038f12e065538f9c

Assume we have only one patient right now, but tomorrow we can have more so anyway we have to GROUP BY _CDRId_ and _BillingMonth_

Comment: If cant use GROUP BY clause then leave it. Can we do it some logic ?

Comment: Now explain what do you want to achieve by inserting GROUP BY. It will collapse all rows with the same CDRId into one row. The best way is to add more rows with another `CDRId` value(s) into fiddle source data and show the output for such data.

Comment: Done. Updated the fiddle. I want to see which patient went for checkup with accumulating duration for each month individually. Here's the updated fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=861e63261cf234bc1b043f8a07a8797f

Comment: @Akina, I've added a screenshot in the question

Comment: Avoid using variables. They still worked in MySQL 5.7 but they are now deprecated in MySQL 8.x.

Comment: *The best way is to add more rows with another CDRId value(s) into fiddle source data and show the output **for such data.*** Now the fiddle data and desired output screenshot differs dramatically.

Comment: @Akina, Sorry i added the wrong screenshot. Please see the updated one.

Comment: ??? fiddle contains the data for 3 CDRId, screenshot shows 4. And dates/durations does not match too...

Comment: @Akina, No no Sir. The screenshot is just for reference. That I want this type of grouping.

Comment: @Akina, I just wanted to show that I want this type of grouping on the basis of _BillingMonth_ for each Person.

Comment: I do not see the grouping. And screenshot explains nothing - what GROUP BY must do? if you mean that it must join a lot of "cells" vertically - then SQL can do this never and noway. This is the work for your client output-generating subsystem - hide a value if the value in the previous row is the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221935/discussion-between-tanzeel-and-akina).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SQL has no way of "merging table cells" like you show in your screenshot. SQL is not like a spreadsheet.

You must fetch the rows and then work out in application code how you want to group them.

(You asked me on [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63998521/20860) to come here and give an answer.)